# Moderators should be able to retract erroneous migrations

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, migration-rejection

Recently, a moderator erroneously migrated my question.

The moderator admitted that my question was erroneously migrated, but he told **me** to ask the receiving site's moderators to reject the migration.

That is crazy. I did nothing wrong. Why do I have to chase this question with other moderators who had nothing to do with the erroneous migration? The moderator made a mistake. Why can't he/she retract the migration?

Comment: "The moderator admitted that my question was erroreously [sic] migrated" - I take it you're not referring to Ruben's migration, that you [previously contested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377479/461068)? Because [I see no such admission from him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377479/how-can-we-help-moderators-who-are-multi-tasking-and-not-actually-reading-conten#comment1259600_377479) regarding that.

Answer (score 25):

You're right that *you* shouldn't need to chase down moderators if it wasn't your mistake. If the moderator made the mistake, they can easily flag the post or even directly ping the mods of that site in the private moderator chat to fix the mistake.

But in this case, the moderator doesn't believe the migration was in error, which presents a significant problem for you in wanting it rejected and moved back. Even if you manage to convince moderators on the other site to reject it, that won't reopen your question on the origin site. It'll just change to being closed as off-topic and would still need to be reopened. So inherently the feature you request would not even be useful to you since the moderators on the origin site do not agree.

Addressing your specific request: Having a feature for a moderator of one site to forcibly pull a question back from another can cause some serious headaches if it got more activity there. Technically, a moderator could somewhat-undo a migration by clearing the migration history, but that would still leave an open exact duplicate on another site, which is not a preferable state of being - it is only meant to be used to clear the history of migration in true cases of error, not to manually pull back a question. In the end, the other site needs to agree with the rejection, which means some manual communication has to exist. Your only recourse in this situation is to get both sites to agree.

Answer (score 8):

We are able to restore the situation on our own site, and I scienced it out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377454/should-we-have-multiple-languages-on-this-stack-exchange-site?noredirect=1).

There's an option to clear migration history in the mod menu:

[image]

And that unlocks and reopens the question:

[image]

It does leave the question on the target site - for that you do need the help of that site's moderators.

Comment: This doesn't remove it from the site it was moved to, however.

Comment: OK, but that's something you can leave a flag for...